# csv writing within loop

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv
a=[]
with open('large.csv','w') as f1:
    writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',)

    for i in range(1000000):
        for j in range(i+1):
            a.append(i+j*0.2)
            #print i,j,a
        #want to write into same csv file???
        '''like            
               0     1     2......999999
            0  0.0
            1  1.0  1.2
            2  2.0  2.2   2.4
            .   .....
            .   .....
            999999
        ''' 
        a=[]
```

I have done this to avoid same caculation twice and as the list 'a' will grow large I have to initialize it again(after one iteration of the outer loop) .So, I want the list(before get initialized again) written  into csv file in the above manner but I am not able to do so......please help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do you want to do something like this?

```
import csv
with open('large.csv','w') as f1:
    writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',)
    for i in range(1000000):
        row = [i + j*0.2 for j in range(i+1)]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

or also with the row/column headers:

```
import csv
with open('large.csv','w') as f1:
    writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',)
    writer.writerow([''] + range(1000000))
    for i in range(1000000):
        row = [i] + [i + j*0.2 for j in range(i+1)]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

The latter returns the following file (I have replaced 1000000 with 10):

```
        0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
0       0.0
1       1.0     1.2
2       2.0     2.2     2.4
3       3.0     3.2     3.4     3.6
4       4.0     4.2     4.4     4.6     4.8
5       5.0     5.2     5.4     5.6     5.8     6.0
6       6.0     6.2     6.4     6.6     6.8     7.0     7.2
7       7.0     7.2     7.4     7.6     7.8     8.0     8.2     8.4
8       8.0     8.2     8.4     8.6     8.8     9.0     9.2     9.4     9.6
9       9.0     9.2     9.4     9.6     9.8     10.0    10.2    10.4    10.6    10.8
```

Comment: @tanmay: Great to hear it, and good to have you on StackOverflow. You can show that this answer solved your problem by clicking on the checkmark next to it. Since your reputation has by now reached 16, you can also give upvotes to helpful answers by clicking on the upwards triangle above the checkmark as a token of your appreciation.

Comment: @Raz - me too, just wasn't sure OP is not using Python 3.x